# How to center navbar content after menu collapse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a website which needs to have two headers. The second header holds the social icons (facebook, twitter, linkedin, google plus) and next to them I have this heading:"Fast Social Login>>" .

Initially, with the css, I pulled them to the right. I am using the 'collapse' and 'navbar-collapse' classes for the heading because I don't want it to be shown on smaller screens. However, when this heading collapses, I want the social icons to be centered on the navbar.

Can this be solved with CSS adjustment or do I need to write scripts?

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top header-bottom-border">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="#"><img src="img/googleplus.png" class="social-position pull-right"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="img/linkedin.png" class="social-position pull-right"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="img/twitter.png" class="social-position pull-right"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="img/facebook.png" class="social-position pull-right"></a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <h2 class=" navbar-text pull-right" style="color: #b0b0b0">FAST SOCIAL LOGIN>></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header-bottom-border{
    border-width: 0 0 5px 0;
    border-color: #4c9322;
}
.social-position{
    width: 3em;
    height: 3em;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: not sure if I understand your question properly but if you are wanting different style for different resolutions have a google for media queries

Comment: Can you give me some links of what you mean please?

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=media+queries+css&oq=media+quer&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l4j69i60.3384j0j8&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `text-align: center` with media query?
See the exact width when your `navbar-collapse` collapses, and write a query for that width.

```
@media (max-width: width-when-navbar-collapses) {
    .container {
        text-align: center;
        a {
            float: none;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and nothing happens. The icons are still pulled to the right. Does it mean that the 'pull-right' class has priority over the media query ?

Comment: You need to set the `float: none` on `<a>` elements also, I overlooked that class. I modified my original post.

Comment: I have made some changes to the code that you suggested and it works perfectly now. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Just saw it now that I wrote in SASS style, sorry for that, I was busy. Glad I could be of help. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible by only using CSS, more specific, by using [media-queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Looking at the [Bootstrap-source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/navbar.less#L63) for the navbar, they use a media-query with a specific variable to change the behaviour of the navbar depending on the device-width:

```
@media (min-width: @grid-float-breakpoint)
```

Using a mobile-first approach, what you would need to do is set the social icons to be centered per default and override this using this media - query that targets the minimum width and above.

This could be achieved with something like in this example:

```
.navbar .container {
    text-align: center;

    .pull-right {
        // you probably need to override these in here
        float: none;
    }

    @media (min-width: @grid-float-breakpoint){
        text-align: start ;

        .pull-right {
            float: right;
        }
    }
}
```

In case you're not using LESS (or any other preprocessor) and you have the compiled version of bootstrap in your project, the default-value of `@grid-float-breakpoint` is `768px`, as defined [here in the source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/variables.less#L275)

Comment: Davion's suggestion works perfectly. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@media (max-width: width-when-navbar-collapses) {
    .container a{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .container a img {
        display: table;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: Davion's suggestion works perfectly. I appreciate your help.